# Running multiple event macros

Tags: vba, excel, date, auto-populate

I discovered this Event macro and it is exactly what I need. However I have multiple points of data entry that need to generate a static date and timestamp. I have not been successful in running multiple instances of this macro.

Example: I enter data in A, date and time generate in C,D. Then I enter data in J, date and time generate in M,N. etc.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
Set A = Range("D:D")
Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
For Each r In Inte
    If r.Value > 0 Then
       r.Offset(0, -3).Value = Date
       r.Offset(0, -3).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
       r.Offset(0, -2).Value = Time
       r.Offset(0, -2).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Else
       r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ""
       r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ""
    End If
Next r

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To include column J, Change:

```
Set A = Range("D:D")
```

to:

```
Set A = Range("D:D,J:J")
```